# XML::LibXML::XPathContext fails parsing Google Maps kml file - doesn't find "when" nodes

Tags: xml, perl, google-maps, xpath, kml

I am unable to get Perl to read Google `LocationHistory.kml` files using XML::LibXML. `findnodes()` doesn't find `when` tags but does find `gx:coord` tags.

If I modify the XML file to put `gx:` in front of `when`, it works. But this isn't what Google produces with their takeout service.

I'd like to read their file without modifying it first.

**INPUT DATA FILE - from Google's Takeout service**

```
#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' xmlns:gx='http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2'>
<Document>
    <Placemark>
        <open>1</open>
        <gx:Track>
            <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
            <when>2018-05-17T15:59:24Z</when>
            <gx:coord>-98.0896248 29.997944600000004 258</gx:coord>
            <when>2018-05-17T15:59:24Z</when>
            <gx:coord>-98.0896248 29.997944600000004 258</gx:coord>
            <when>2018-05-17T15:59:23Z</when>
            <gx:coord>-98.0896647 29.9979384 258</gx:coord>
            <when>2018-05-17T15:45:14Z</when>
            <gx:coord>-98.0896772 29.9979363 258</gx:coord>
            <when>2018-05-17T15:40:08Z</when>
            <gx:coord>-98.0892224 29.9977119 262</gx:coord>
        </gx:Track>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

**MY CODE**

```
#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
sub Test {
my ($infile) = @_;
my ($dom, $xpc, @gnodes, @wnodes);


$dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $infile);

$xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($dom);
$xpc->registerNs('xmlns',    'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2');
$xpc->registerNs('xmlns:gx', 'http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2');

# should find 5
(@wnodes) = $xpc->findnodes('//when');
print 'XPath: //when      Matched:  ', scalar(@wnodes), "\n";;

# should find 5
(@gnodes) = $xpc->findnodes('//gx:coord');
say 'XPath: //gx:coord  Matched:  ', scalar(@gnodes);

};


THE OUTPUT - five <gx:coord> found, but zero <when> nodes found
searching for <gx:when> also produces zero results
#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Apple-iMac21:NewProgramLocal user$

XPath: //when      Matched:  0
XPath: //gx:coord  Matched:  5


Apple-iMac21:NewProgramLocal user$
```

Comment: When no namespace is specified, an element will be in the default namespace. Have you tried looking for 'xmlns:when'?

Comment: (@wnodes) = $xpc->findnodes('//xmlns:when');  -- produces correct result.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

The prefixes used by the XPaths need not match the prefixes used in the XML. In fact, when a default namespace is used in the XML (as is the case here), a prefix is required for XPaths even though none are used in the XML. Simply choose prefixes meaningful to you for use in the XPaths.

Also note that `registerNs` takes but a prefix, so do not include `xmlns:`.

So changing:

```perl
$xpc->registerNs('xmlns',    'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2');
$xpc->registerNs('xmlns:gx', 'http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2');
(@wnodes) = $xpc->findnodes('//when');
```

to:

```perl
$xpc->registerNs('main', 'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2');
$xpc->registerNs('gx',   'http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2');
(@wnodes) = $xpc->findnodes('//main:when');
```

yields the expected:

```
XPath: //when      Matched:  5
XPath: //gx:coord  Matched:  5
```

Comment: Nice, clean meaningful prefixes would be `kml` and `kmlext`. I'd go with `k` and `kx`.

Comment: @ikegami since you already modified almost every single word of my answer, you could as well have changed the prefixes... Please post your text as your own answer and I will then delete mine, it seems more logical.

Comment: This suggestion solves my problem - using the appropriate prefix with //when tag. Since the actual file that google produces uses xmlns and gx as prefixes, I'll stick with those - it works!

Answer (score 1):

bytepusher's answer above works, as does the second answer. adding "xmlns:" in front of the "when" tag produces the correct result and stays consistent with the file that is downloaded from Google using their Takeout feature (for "location history").

I was assuming xmlns acted as a default that didn't need to be specified in an xpath search, but that was a bad assumption.

Thanks for the help!